# Java enum doesnt store new data

Tags: java, enums

I have created a small class that I use in order to contact our internal APIs.
instead of creating new connections and passing parameters, I have this class that does all the work.
The Enum is something like this

```
public enum EnumTypes {
    UpdateA("update",PostGetEnum.Post),
    UpdateB("update2",PostGetEnum.Post);
    private Map<String, String> values=new HashMap<String, String>();
 ....
    public void addValues(String name,String value) {
         values.put(name, value);
     }
    public Map<String, String> getValues() {
       return values;
    }
}
```

So i am creating an object like this

```
EnumTypes test = EnumTypes.UpdateA;
        test.addValues("id", "1");
```

It is working just fine, except something that I just noticed. When I create a second Object like so

```
EnumTypes test2 = EnumTypes.UpdateA;
        test2.addValues("id", "2");
```

they both have the same id.

```
System.out.println(test.getValues());
System.out.println(test2.getValues());
```

> 2
> 2

Is there something that i am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by _create a second Object_? Enum constants are singletons.

Comment: There is only one instance of each constant of an enum. `test` and `test2` refer to the same object. It looks like you're trying to use an enum for something that it's not intended for. When you do `EnumTypes test2 = EnumTypes.UpdateA;` you are not creating a second object.

Comment: Both `test` and `test2` refer to the same object referred to as `EnumTypes.UpdateA`.

Comment: Enums shouldn't be mutable. If you want to associate an enum constant with a `Map<String, String>`, use an `EnumMap`.

Comment: "today I learned that Enums are Static... who knew?!" static-ness isn't directly relevant. If you had a class like `class A { String string; }`, and an instance `A someA = new A();`, then `A anotherA = someA;` doesn't create a copy of `someA`: `someA.string = "hello"` would also change `anotherA.string`, because they are the same instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enum instances are `static` so there can only be one instance which is created at class-loading time, maybe an Enum is not what you want here.

Think of using enum the same way you would use a `final static` field